# Intermittent 401 Unauthorized from Google GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

We are getting intermittent 401 Unauthorized errors from Google's GCM service. In the past, it worked 100% of the time. The problem might coincide with our routers accepting IPv6 traffic, but the problem remains now even if we disable IPv6 on the adapter. It also doesn't work on a separate IPv4-only network. We also retry our requests using Google's recommended exponential back-off (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#retry), so the problem could have been developing over time and we might have not noticed.

All the production IPv4 and IPv6 addresses we've tested are listed in our project at:
https://console.developers.google.com

Here is what our key looks like, we've got our entire publicly accessible subnet listed for testing, but I've tried with just single IP addresses as well.

[image]

Sometimes it works:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>curl --header "Authorization: key=REDACTED" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googl
eapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"test\"],\"data\":{\"code\":123}
}" -k
{"multicast_id":REDACTED,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"r
esults":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

But, sometimes we get this response:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>curl --header "Authorization: key=REDACTED" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googl
eapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"test\"],\"data\":{\"code\":123}
}" -k
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Minor Update (4/10/2014)**

Changing the settings to "Any IP allowed" fixes the problem, but changing to any other IP address or addresses breaks it again.

Comment: Facing the same problem here, but changing settings to "Any IP allowed" does not fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a service reliability issue.

Comment: I think it falls squarely within the guidelines as a question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" or "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", as the GCM service is used by most android apps. I see that I don't have an explicit question now, but I think it's implied that I am asking if anyone else with a similar setup has experienced this issue and how they worked around it. Either with a setting change or a programmatic solution like exponential back-off.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate the server key by leaving the ip address field as blank solved the issue.

Comment: Not providing an IP address does "solve" the problem, and I added that to the question. However, our goal is to use the IP address restriction as suggested by Google in their docs, "... To prevent quota theft, restrict your key so that requests are only allowed from your servers' source IP addresses." See: [Developers Console - API keys](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys)